# Upgrading openssl on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS - Heartbleed

Tags: 10.04, openssl

I have a Server which is using `Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS`. I read that this OS version is not effected because it comes with older version of openssl, 0.9.8 or similar. But my Server show following on running `openssl version -a` which means its openssl was updated.

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
built on: Tue Mar 27 14:41:54 EDT 2012
platform: linux-x86_64
```

When I check our website hosted on this Server via `filippo.io/Heartbleed` it says site was not affected

I still tried to update my Server via `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` but openssl version still remains the same.

I have two questions

1. Do I need to upgrade my openssl?
2. How do I do it on Ubuntu 10.04.4?

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/587329/heartbleed-what-is-it-and-what-are-options-to-mitigate-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I need to upgrade my openssl?

No.

> [Ubuntu Security Notice USN-2165-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/)
>
> 7th April, 2014 openssl vulnerabilities
>
> A security issue affects these releases of Ubuntu and its derivatives:
>
> ```
> Ubuntu 13.10
> Ubuntu 12.10
> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
> ```

There is no mentioning of 10.04 so it is not affected. These kind of messages always list all the supported and affected systems (hence 13.04 not being listed since that went end of life).

By the way: the bug got introduced with 12.04.

---

> How do I do it on Ubuntu 10.04.4?

You do not.

Some more information can be found at the official notices from Canonical [CVE-2014-0160](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0160.html) and [CVE-2014-0076](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0076.html). Here ALL supported systems will get listed:

```
Upstream:   released (1.0.1g)
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx):  not-affected (code not present)
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin):    released (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12)
Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal): released (1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.7)
Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander):    released (1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr): released (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2)
```

As you can see the bug got introduced in 12.04 and was not present in 10.04.